# How to forbid focusout when input value is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's some text input fields( 3+ ) as following:

```
A:__ B:__ C:__
```

the js will validate the value when focusout the input field, I wanna it still focus in the current field if invalid, but cannot make it, here's my codes:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-short">
  <input type="text" data-mini="true" id="no1" name="no1" maxlength="2" placeholder="#1" />
</div>
<div class="input-short">
  <input type="text" data-mini="true" id="no2" name="no2" maxlength="2" placeholder="#2" />
</div>
<div class="input-short">
  <input type="text" data-mini="true" id="no3" name="no3" maxlength="2" placeholder="#3" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-short {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#no1').focusout(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "" ||
       $(this).val() == $('#no2').val() ||
       $(this).val() == $('#no3').val() )
    {
        alert( "no" );
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
$('#no2').focusout(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "" ||
       $(this).val() == $('#no1').val() ||
       $(this).val() == $('#no3').val() )
    {
        alert( "no" );
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

The "$(this).focus();" doesn't function, it'll focus on the next input field, how to permit it focusout only when the input value is valid?

Comment: I tried your code in JSFiddle ([http://jsfiddle.net/cBAyP/](http://jsfiddle.net/cBAyP/)), and it seemed to do what you want it to do. It's also a really obnoxious function -- for example, when a field is invalid, I couldn't change browser tabs, applications, or anything -- so I'd recommend you find a more user-friendly way to deal with invalid fields.

Comment: You should be using the blur event and not focusout. There are distinct differences between the two where focusout event also checks for focus on child elements and is non-W3C compliant if I remember correctly. Also, you can fix what Zaid said by just removing the alert and have some other means of displaying the error on page!

Comment: This sounds like a really really bad idea.  Forcing focus until the user has entered a valid value - have you ever seen that functionality on a website?  I haven't - for good reason.

Comment: Thank you all guys, by now the function doesn't work, it'll alert a message but then focus on next input field, in jquery mobile framework.
What I want to realize is "lottery sales", you know the numbers can't be duplicated. Maybe you guys are right, show the invalid numbers in red color is a better choice.

Comment: Anyway, as a technical problem, anybody has a solution -- focus in the current field?